# Close the activity from a broadcast receiver

Tags: java, android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

My Project is about the call recorder.
I want when the call received, my transparent activity open with a button.
I open my activity from my broadcast receiver class.
in this activity, I have a toggle button to activate or deactivate my application.
When a call received, if my toggle button is on, it starts to record the call.
it works OK but when the call is finished, I close my activity from my broadcast receiver class.
like this: first, this is my activity when the call received:

```
   public class Test extends Activity {
static Test tes;
ToggleButton toggleButton;
TextView txt_disable, txt_enable;
private static Context context;
private BroadcastReceiver _closeActivityReceiver = new CloseActivityReceiver();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);

    tes = this;
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("closeNoInternetActivity");
    this.registerReceiver(_closeActivityReceiver, filter);

    toggleButton = findViewById(R.id.togglebtn);
    txt_enable = findViewById(R.id.txt_enable);
    txt_disable = findViewById(R.id.txt_disable);


    if (isActivityRunning(MainActivity.class)) {
        MainActivity.getInstance().finish();

    }
    final SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("TOGGLE", MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean sie = pref.getBoolean("STATE", true);

    if (sie == true) {
        Log.i("mhs", "true");
        //to main activity toggleRecord fal hast pass inja user agar bekhad mitone k disable kone
        toggleButton.setChecked(true);
        toggleButton.setText(null);
        toggleButton.setTextOn(null);
        toggleButton.setTextOff(null);
        toggleButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.record_btn);
        txt_disable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                toggleRecord.setChecked(false);
                toggleButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.not_recording_btn);
                finishAffinity();
            }
        });

    } else {
        Log.i("mhs", "false");
        toggleButton.setChecked(false);
        toggleButton.setText(null);
        toggleButton.setTextOn(null);
        toggleButton.setTextOff(null);
        toggleButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.not_recording_btn);
        txt_enable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                toggleRecord.setChecked(true);
                toggleButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.record_btn);
                finishAffinity();
            }
        });


    }


}

protected Boolean isActivityRunning(Class activityClass) {
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> tasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    for (ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo task : tasks) {
        if (activityClass.getCanonicalName().equalsIgnoreCase(task.baseActivity.getClassName()))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

private class CloseActivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // close this damn activity!

    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    this.unregisterReceiver(this._closeActivityReceiver);
}
public static Test getInstance() {
    return tes;
}
}
```

and here is my receiver:
here I start an activity from the receiver like this when I have a phone call

```
switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            isIncoming = true;
            callStartTime = new Date();
            savedNumber = number;
            onIncomingCallStarted(context, number, callStartTime);
            Intent i = new Intent(context, Test.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);

            Log.i("mhs","zang khord");
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            if (lastState != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                isIncoming = false;
                callStartTime = new Date();
                onOutgoingCallStarted(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
                Log.i("mhs","ghat kard");
            } else {
                isIncoming = true;
                callStartTime = new Date();
                onIncomingCallAnswered(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
                //vaghti zang mikhore va ghat mikone dar akhar
                Log.i("mhs","ghatid");
                Intent in = new Intent("closeNoInternetActivity");
                context.sendBroadcast(in);
            }
```

and here I close it like this:

```
   case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            if (lastState != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                isIncoming = false;
                callStartTime = new Date();
                onOutgoingCallStarted(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
                Log.i("mhs","ghat kard");
            } else {
                isIncoming = true;
                callStartTime = new Date();
                onIncomingCallAnswered(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
                //vaghti zang mikhore va ghat mikone dar akhar
                Log.i("mhs","ghatid");
                Intent in = new Intent("closeNoInternetActivity");
                context.sendBroadcast(in);
            }
```

My problem is that I think my activity doesn't close, and it reminds in the background and causes my activity is transparent, then again I have a phone call. my ringing screen doesn't show on screen. 
I think If I able to close my Test activity in right way, my problem solved.

Comment: Most important: is your `BroadcastReceiver` receiving the `Intent` or not?

Comment: I start activity  from my BroadcastReceiver and finish it again.

Comment: It would probably make sense to use the BroadcastReceiver to then broadcast a local message that the Activity can register a listener for then the code to finish the activity can remain in the activity rather than trying to close it externally. Have you tried this approach?

Comment: i register my receiver in my activity

Answer (score -1):

Just copy and paste below code. it should work. If it doesn't then try modifying finish method you can explicitly call `destroy` method if needed.

```
public class Test extends Activity {
static Test tes;
private static Context context;
ToggleButton toggleButton;
TextView txt_disable, txt_enable;
private BroadcastReceiver _closeActivityReceiver = new CloseActivityReceiver();

public static Test getInstance() {
    return tes;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);

    tes = this;
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("closeNoInternetActivity");
    this.registerReceiver(_closeActivityReceiver, filter);

    toggleButton = findViewById(R.id.togglebtn);
    txt_enable = findViewById(R.id.txt_enable);
    txt_disable = findViewById(R.id.txt_disable);


    if (isActivityRunning(MainActivity.class)) {
        MainActivity.getInstance().finish();

    }
    final SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("TOGGLE", MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean sie = pref.getBoolean("STATE", true);

    if (sie == true) {
        Log.i("mhs", "true");
        //to main activity toggleRecord fal hast pass inja user agar bekhad mitone k disable kone
        toggleButton.setChecked(true);
        toggleButton.setText(null);
        toggleButton.setTextOn(null);
        toggleButton.setTextOff(null);
        toggleButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.record_btn);
        txt_disable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                toggleRecord.setChecked(false);
                toggleButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.not_recording_btn);
                finishAffinity();
            }
        });

    } else {
        Log.i("mhs", "false");
        toggleButton.setChecked(false);
        toggleButton.setText(null);
        toggleButton.setTextOn(null);
        toggleButton.setTextOff(null);
        toggleButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.not_recording_btn);
        txt_enable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                toggleRecord.setChecked(true);
                toggleButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.record_btn);
                finishAffinity();
            }
        });


    }


}

protected Boolean isActivityRunning(Class activityClass) {
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> tasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    for (ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo task : tasks) {
        if (activityClass.getCanonicalName().equalsIgnoreCase(task.baseActivity.getClassName()))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    this.unregisterReceiver(this._closeActivityReceiver);
}

public void finish() {
    super.finish();
}

private class CloseActivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // close this damn activity!

        finish();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: nothing change , my activity still not closed. I can not understand you means " it should work. If it doesn't then try modifying finish method you can explicitly call destroy method if needed."

Comment: Can you provide more information like from where you're sending broadcast and when? edit your question*

Comment: In my broadcast When I have a phone call ,I start my activity and when the phone call finishied , I finish my activity from broadcast

Comment: try debugging your code and see if `onReceive()` method has been called or not. put a toast and check both cases while application is in background or destroyed.